# Display all entries in a table using for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to display all entries present in a table in my MySQL database using `for` loop (I need `for` loop for some reason, `while` loop is not an option). Although I can do it properly in `while` loop I can't seem to manage to do it with `for` loop.

Here is my while loop code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{
    echo "<p> " . $row['column-name'] . " </p>";
}
```

How can I convert this to `for` loop? I mean how to navigate to each rows using for loop's counter variable?

```
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);    

for ($i = $counter; $i > 0; $i--) 
{ 
    echo ????;
}
```

How should I echo the column name and use the `$i` as the row reference?

Comment: Tell us why do you need a `for` loop?

Comment: because i have to echo it in reverse order

Comment: personally I'd keep the while loop and change the SQL to return your data in reverse order using `ORDER BY {some-field} DESC`

Comment: you mean by using DESC right ?. i never thought of that. sorry for such a dumb question. fixed it.

Comment: exactly, see: [Sorting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) - no worries bud, we all get brain freeze

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable outside while loop(thus you get a row reference)

 Code shown below

```
$i=0; // this refer every row..now its 0
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{
    echo "<p> " . $row['column-name'] . " </p>";
    $i++;  
}
```

And if you need FOR loop

```
 
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
    {

       // thus you get $i as row reference

    }
```

> mysqli_fetch_all returns both numeric and assoc array, so dont forget to select MYSQLI_ASSOC or
> MYSQLI_NUM

Comment: yes but i need it in for loop. and where did you use the $i ?

Comment: @TheJoker..updated answer... if that helps, dont forget to select this as answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you need the rows to be outputted in the reverse (descending) order, why not just `ORDER BY {field} DESC` in the query?

Then you can use `foreach()` to run through all of the results, like this:

```
$res = $db->query ('SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC');
$output = '';
foreach ($res->fetch_array () as $line) {
    $output .= "<p>{$line['column']}</p>\n";
}
```

As you can see, no need for a for loop, a while loop, nor any other fancy tricks. Just echo `$output` wherever you need it, and the results are sorted just the way you want them.